# How to raise this div to the top?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<style>
#left{
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    border:2px solid black; 
}

#down{
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid black;
    float:left;
}
#right{
    width:40%;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid black;
    float:right;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="down"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i get "right" div to the right-top without changing anything inside html?
On [First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnZgO.jpg) is how it looks like
On [Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yki5.jpg) is how it need to look like.
Also i don't need to use relative absolute because if i zoom or un-zoom it will be messed up

Comment: negative margin-top ?

Comment: if i use margin top when i zoom or unzoom also messed up

Comment: absolute positioning, or even better, flex box with justified content

Comment: Wrap `left` & `down` in their own div and float *that*...

Answer (score 2):

is use this, it works for this example

EDIT : i put "justify-content:space-between" in body to be exactly like your picture

```css
#left{
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid black; 
}

#down{
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid black;
}
#right{
    width:40%;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
 
body{display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content:space-between;}

.box:nth-child(2){
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<html>


<body>
    <div class="box" id="left"></div>
    <div class="box"  id="down"></div>
    <div class="box"  id="right"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use flexbox, but you need a container for the items.
Maybe  is so generic.

```
body {display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;}
```

Comment: nope bcz instead of left-right-down (position of block) you got down-right-left

Comment: Yes, need to order.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

Added

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
```

to `#right`

```css
#left{

width:50%;
height:200px;
float:left;
border:2px solid black; 
}

#down{

width:50%; 
height:200px;
border:2px solid black;
float:left;
}
#right{


width:40%;
height:200px;
border:2px solid black;
position:absolute;
right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="down"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use display:inline-block and vertical-align:top instead of float.

```
#left, #right, #down {
```

display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;}

Answer (score -1):

the best way is just add `#right{transform:translatey(-100%);}`